# How to send video as file with aiogram (python)?

Tags: python, telegram

I need to send video as file, but if I use "message.answer_document" my bot sends simple video with compression. How can I fix it?

my code:

```
async def send_video(message: types.Message):
   files = os.listdir("path")
   video = open('path'+files[1], 'rb')
   await message.answer_document(video)
   video.close()
```

Comment: You need to show work at least

Comment: @drum I added my code to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands = ["video"])
async def send_video(message: types.Message):
    video = open("name", "rb")
    await bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video = video)
```

*I can only offer this option. No answer.*

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31350324)